# [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown fragment

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, webpack-encore

I want to use some fragment:

```
import {gql} from "apollo-boost";
import "../fragments/cardFragments.graphql"

export const ADD_CARD = gql`
    mutation AddCard {
        createCard(input: {
            private: true,
            section: "school",
            createdBy: "api/users/1"
        }) {
            card {
                ...CardFields
            }
        }
    }
`;

export default {ADD_CARD}
```

cardFragments.graphql:

```
fragment CardFields on card {
    id
    private
    section
    createdBy {
        id
    }
}
```

Inside the console I get the error :

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown fragment "CardFields"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

Did I forgot something?

**EDIT:**

For the graphql fragmets to work I need to load it with webpack: [Apollo docs](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#webpack-loading-and-preprocessing)

I did this with `Webpack Encore`:

```
.addLoader({
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
});

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Before I did this - I got an error for the not loadable .graphql extention inside of `Webpack Encore`.

Is there something I do not see about creating cutsom loader with `Webpack Encore`?

Comment: It's really unclear what you expect `import "../fragments/cardFragments.graphql"` to do. A graphql file is not even valid JS code, so you must be relying on some build tool as well?

Comment: @Bergi, most likely [graphql-tag/loader](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#webpack-loading-and-preprocessing) for webpack

Comment: @JosephD. Is that implied by the `apollo-client` tag?

Comment: @Bergi yes. Apollo is a graphql client.

Comment: Ok, I use webpack encore with symfony and created a custom loader: with the [description form the docs](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#webpack-loading-and-preprocessing) - before I did this I got an error that this file format can not be loaded. So now it gets loaded. Should I register that somewere in the new ApolloClient() function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should `import { CardFields } from "../fragments/cardFragments.js"` and then use this fragment in your mutation like this:

```js
import {gql} from "apollo-boost";
import { CARD_FEILDS } from "../fragments/cardFragments.js"

export const ADD_CARD = gql`
    mutation AddCard {
        createCard(input: {
            private: true,
            section: "school",
            createdBy: "api/users/1"
        }) {
            card {
                ...CardFields
            }
        }
    }
    ${CARD_FEILDS}
`;

export default {ADD_CARD}
```

In cardFragments.js:

```js
import {gql} from "apollo-boost"
export const CARD_FEILDS = gql `
  fragment CardFields on card {
    id
    private
    section
    createdBy {
        id
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Thank u for this suggestion. Nice to know tat its possible to solve it this way when the webpack loading configuration does not work at all. 
Do u solve it this way? Its not the recommended way isn't it ?

Comment: @MichaelBrauner I think you should use .js file as much as possible rather than using .graphql file in React app. So you just need babel-loader to compile your file. I think it's better than use .graphql file

Comment: Ok, I will do it this way. Thank you.

Comment: Just so you know you do  not need `gql` on your `fragment`